# How to display Shopware Currency Switch

Tags: shopware

I am currently working on a Shopware Shop and would like to display an currency switch - I have been looking for this on google for two days now and haven't found anything yet. I have also activated the default responsive theme and have had a look in its code but haven't found anything either.

Does anyone know where I could take a look at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your Currencies in Basic Settings -> Shop Settings -> Currencies,

[image: Currencies]

and assign these currencies to your shop in Basic Settings -> Shop Settings -> Shop, in the lower right.
[image: Assign currencies to Shops in the lower right]